# Preparing an Excel 2010 workbook for Excel 2013 compatibility

Tags: worksheet-function, compatibility, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm going through an important workbook currently in Excel 2010 to make sure it's fully compatible with Excel 2013. I found a list of changes to the object model in 2013, but it didn't cover your standard worksheet functions. For example, I know that the rank function is being deprecated in favor of rank.eq and rank.avg. I can't seem to find anywhere a list of worksheet functions deprecated or removed in Excel 2013.

Unfortunately, the Compatibility Checker in Excel only checks for backward compatibility, not forward compatibility.

To make things harder, I don't have Excel 2013 to open it up in. But even if I did, I'd rather be thorough by going through a list of possible issues, rather than just looking around to see if everything looks alright.

So is there a good list anywhere of worksheet functions deprecated or removed in 2013? Or is there a better process to prep an Excel 2010 document to ensure 2013 compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this won't be an issue but I did find a website with some information: [Compatibility issues in Office 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj229903.aspx) Usually they just add stuff instead of removing or changing existing items.